# smiles as if it is/was/were a compliment

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense

Ian grabs Lili as she tries to leave.

Lili: *Let go of me, you sociopath.*

Ian: *You think I'm a sociopath?*

**Ian smiles as if it is/were a compliment.**

- It should be 'were', right? Even though the sentence is written in the present tense?
- Is the sentence written in a perfectly natural way? Could it also be: **Ian smiles as were it a compliment.**

Answer (score 1):

**as if** indicates a hypothetical situation so you should backshift the verb or, for **is**, use the subjunctive **were**.

You are therefore right, the subjunctive **were** is correct in your sentence. **is** is not correct because it's not backshifted. In informal English, you could backshift it to the past simple **was**.

**were it...** is grammatically correct, but very formal. While it can be used following **as**, the set phrase **as if** is very much more widely used, as this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as%20were%20it%20a%2C%20as%20if%20it%20were%20a%2C%20as%20if%20it%20was%20a&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20were%20it%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20it%20were%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20it%20was%20a%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cas%20were%20it%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20it%20were%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20if%20it%20was%20a%3B%2Cc0) shows. **as were it a** enjoyed a very brief blip of popularity around 1900, but at other times over the past 200 years its use is very uncommon.